# Run a script.py and typing the same instructions on the shell is getting 2 different output

Tags: python, shell, vb6

I have a script that connect my gopro via wifi to the PC, makes it take a photo and return as output on screen the path of the photo taken.
My goal is to use that path as variable on my VB6 Program.
I use this code to read the output of the shell

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set wmic = WshShell.Exec("python ""C:\GOPRO\Take_photo.py""")
Do While wmic.Status = 0
    Sleep 100
Loop
parameter = Replace(wmic.StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf, "")
Text1.Text = Text1.Text & parameter
```

The code itself it works, my problem is that doing this way the output i receive is this:
[image]

While if i open the shell and i type manually the same commands contained in the .py file i get this:
[image]

**Can someone please tell me how to get `'http://10.5.5.9:8080/videos/DCIM/100GOPRO/GOPR8674.JPG'` into the textbox?

I guess that is a python problem because even if I run the script outside of VB it end without showing the path.

Is there any chance I can send from VB to a python shell one command the time?
I mean like if I open the shell and type them manually**

Comment: Perhaps the path/filename isn't being output on StdOut, but on another stream?

Comment: which one it can be? I think the problem is not on the VB code cause even if I run the script outside vb it doesn't show the path. It just takes the picture. can you tell me how to put a picture in the comment so i can show you what i mean?

Comment: Update your post with new details.  So do you mean that the script does not output the filename?  Your picture seems to show that it does.

Comment: it does just if I open the shell and I type every command manually, if I create a file.py with the same commands it doesn't. It works but doesn't show the path

Comment: Msgbox out what is being returned. `msgbox wmic.StdOut.ReadAll` You can press Ctrl + C in message boxes to copy to the clipboard. No need to select.

Comment: what do you mean? I don't understand what should I use the msgbox for?

Comment: To see what exactly is being returned.

Comment: Is the same of the first picture.The one in the textbox

Answer (score 0):

Developer of gopro-py-api (library used in python script) here, you'll need to first make sure the URL is sent to stdout using sys.stdout.write().

Also, the URL return is asynchronous so you'll need to implement a timeout

Comment: Hi Konrad, thanks for the script ;) I'm trying to implement it with other function and i would rally appreciate your help since you are the one who created it. Anyway about the sys.stdout write() you mean has to be put on the GoProCamera.py or just on the script I use to call the function?

Comment: I tried to do the same with gopro.listMedia() and this way I get the output but  all the other commands  don't return it

Comment: I will add a verbose flag in the next release for better parsing. I can do it like this: https://i.imgur.com/RIVE9Bh.png but if you want to download the URL directly to your computer: https://i.imgur.com/aw5y5ED.png (JPG file downloaded)

Comment: I actually "fix" the problem using listMedia()! this way stdout gets the output then I just work with the strings in order to get the URL.I would like to talk with you about my project. Do you mind to give me your contact?

Comment: Sure! mail@chernowii.com